# How can we calculate the unit normal $\textbf{N}$ of the sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I want to show that the normal curvature of any curve on a sphere of radius $r$ is $\pm \frac{1}{r}$.

$$$$

The normal curvature is $\kappa_n=\gamma '' \cdot \textbf{N}$, where $\gamma$ is a unit-speed curve and $\textbf{N}$ is the unit normal of the sphere.

I have done the following:

Let $\gamma (t)$ be a unit-speed curve of the sphere with center $\alpha$ and radius $r$.

Then $(\gamma -\alpha) \cdot (\gamma -\alpha )=r^2$.

Differentiating in respect to $t$, we get $$\gamma ' \cdot (\gamma -\alpha )\cdot \gamma '=0 \Rightarrow \gamma ' \cdot (\gamma -\alpha )=0$$

Differentiating again in respect to $t$, we get $$\gamma '' \cdot (\gamma -\alpha )+\gamma ' \cdot \gamma '=0 \Rightarrow \gamma '' \cdot (\gamma -\alpha )=-\gamma ' \cdot \gamma ' =-1$$

Is it correct so far?

How can we calculate the unit normal $\textbf{N}$ of the sphere?

Comment: the unit normal is the same direction as the 'radius vector', and it is orthogonal to every tangent vector.

Comment: yes its correct, and almost complete. A ' missing in the last equality.

Comment: I aded now the missing ' . $$$$ "the unit normal is the same direction as the 'radius vector'" means that $\textbf{N}=\lambda r, \ \lambda >0$, right? $$$$ "the unit normal is orthogonal to every tangent vector" means that $\textbf{N} \cdot \gamma ' =0$, or not? @mlu

Comment: @MaryStar Both claims are true.

Comment: So to get the formula for the normal curvature, do we have to differentiate the equality $\textbf{N} \cdot \gamma ' =0$ ? @HoseynHeydari

Comment: N is a multiple of $\gamma - \alpha$, you have already calculated all the derivatives you need.

Comment: Why is $\textbf{N}$ a multiple of $\gamma-\alpha$ ? I got stuck right now... @mlu

Comment: picture a sphere, and the position as a vector from the centre to the surface

Comment: It stands because the radius vector is equal to the vector $\gamma-\alpha$, right? @mlu

Comment: yes and you already showed this is orthogonal to the tangent

Comment: Differentiating the relation $\textbf{N} \cdot \gamma ' =0$ we get $$\textbf{N}'\cdot \gamma '+\textbf{N}\cdot \gamma ''=0 \Rightarrow \textbf{N}\cdot \gamma ''=-\textbf{N}'\cdot \gamma '$$ 
Therefore, $$\kappa_n=\gamma '' \cdot \textbf{N}=-\textbf{N}'\cdot \gamma '$$ 
$$$$ 
Since $\textbf{N}=\lambda r$, it stands that $\textbf{N}=\lambda(\gamma-\alpha)$. 
$$$$ 
Then $\textbf{N}=\lambda \gamma '$. 
$$$$ 
So, we have $$\kappa_n=-\lambda \gamma '\cdot \gamma '=-\lambda$$ 
$$$$ 
Is this correct? 

How can we find the value of $\lambda$ ? @mlu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33484/discussion-between-mlu-and-mary-star).